# Find all triples of non-negative

Tags: solution-verification

Find all triples of non-negative real numbers $(a,b,c)$ such that:
$$\begin{cases}a^2+ab=c \\ b^2+bc=a \\ c^2+ca=b \end{cases}$$

**Attempt:** $$b= \frac{-c+\sqrt{c^2-4a}}{2}$$ $$2c^2+2ca=-c+\sqrt{c^2-4a}$$ $$2c^2+c(2a+1)=+\sqrt{c^2-4a}$$ $$4c^2+2c^3(2a+1)+4a^2+4a+1=c^2-4a$$

Applies the quadratic formula again and leaves $a$ in terms of $c$. Finally, we have $b$ in terms of $c$, since $c^2+ca=b$. Then we have all the solutions with $a$ varying

Am I right?

Comment: The discriminants are $c^2+4a$,.... ,instead of $c^2-4a$,.....

Comment: The only real solutions are $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0),(\frac12,\frac12,\frac12)$

Answer (score 0):

Take the product of all 3 equations.

$$
a(a+b) = c\\
b(b+c) = a\\
c(c+a) = b\\
a(a+b)b(b+c)c(c+a) = cab\\
$$

Supposing $abc$ is not equal to $0$

$$
x \equiv a+b\\
y \equiv b+c\\
z \equiv c+a\\
xyz = 1\\
$$

Parameterizing all solutions to that last equation is more straightforward. Then once you have a solution $(x,y,z)$ to this equation, going back to $a,b,c$ is solving linear equations.

Comment: @AHusan: I am affraid dear friend your answer is not good. The only non-negative real solutions are $a=b=c$ so $a=0$ and $a=\dfrac12$. For example for $(x,y,z)=(5,\frac15,1)$ you get a solution with $(a,b,c)=(2.9,2.1,-1.9)$ so one of the values is negative, excepting when the only two cases above. Regards.